# mosquitto_sub error. Error: Problem setting TLS options: File not found

Tags: ssl, openssl, mqtt, tls1.2, mosquitto

I am using Windows 11.

I try to use SSL-TLS with Mosquitto Broker.

I have created the certificates correctly.

When try to run

```
mosquitto_sub -h 192.168.68.131 -p 8883 -t test --cafile /mosquitto/certs/ca.crt --tls-version tlsv1.2
```

It gives me

```
Error: Problem setting TLS options: File not found.
```

I already check the internet options to make tls versions enable.
The question already on Stack Overflow but the answers not for Windows and are not accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Windows user you have to use paths in Windows style, not Linux style.

Use something like  `--cafile "C:\Program Files (x86)\mosquitto\certs\ca.crt"`

Verify the path, but your command re-written would be:

```
mosquitto_sub -h 192.168.68.131 -p 8883 -t test --cafile "C:\Program Files (x86)\mosquitto\certs\ca.crt" --tls-version tlsv1.2
```